# Split a line read from a file in C++

Tags: c++, file, fstream, getline

How do I access individual elements of a line read from a file?

I used the following to read a line from a file:

```
getline(infile, data) // where infile is an object of ifstream and data is the variable where the line will be stored
```

The following line is stored in data : "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"

How do I access particular elements of the line now? What if I want to play around with the second element ( quick ) of the line or get hold of a certain word in the line? How do I select it?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Which version of `getline` are you using? That is, is `data` a `string` or a `char[]`? And do you want to learn fundamentals by iterating around in the container yourself, or learn a high-level tool like `stringstream`?

Comment: @Beta data is a string. I just want to find a simple solution that can just store each element of the line in a variable.

Comment: You can split the line (as a string) on space into a vector of string objects, then manipulate the items in the vector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I iterate over the words of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

`data = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"` and the data is string , your string delimeter is `" "`,you can use `std::string::find()` to find the position of the string delimeter and `std::string::substr()` to get a token:

```
std::string data = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
std::string delimiter = " ";
std::string token = data.substr(0, data.find(delimiter)); // token is "the"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your text is space separated, you can use `std::istringstream` to separate the *words*.

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
const std::string data = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
std::string w;
std::istringstream text_stream(data);
while (text_stream >> w)
{
    words.push_back(w);
    std::cout << w << "\n";
}
```

The `operator>>` will read characters into a string until a space is found.